# TMENU in Typo3 - insert url from level above

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript

I have a `TMENU`, and in that menu I would like to insert an URL from "Level 1" into a `wrap` item in "Level 2".

Current TypoScript looks like this:

```
10 = HMENU
10 {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1

        NO = 1
        NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
        NO.allWrap.insertData = 1
        NO.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title
    }

    2 = TMENU
    2 {
        expAll = 1
        stdWrap.wrap = <ul><li><a href="*****URL FROM LEVEL 1 SHOULD BE HERE*****"></a></li>|</ul>

        NO = 1
        NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
        NO.allWrap.insertData = 1
        NO.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title
    }
}
```

Any hints? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stdWrap` properties are executed in a defined order (as they appear in documentation), see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html#prepend

Knowing that `prepend` is executed before `wrap3` allows to solve this challenge.

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = HMENU
page.10 {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        NO = 1
        NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
        NO.allWrap.insertData = 1
        NO.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title
    }

    2 = TMENU
    2 {
        expAll = 1
        stdWrap.prepend = TEXT
        stdWrap.prepend {
          # remove `value` if page title shall be used
          value = URL from Level 1
          # using <current-page>.pid value pointing to previous level
          typolink.parameter.field = pid
          wrap = <li>|</li>
        }
        # `wrap3` is executed after `prepend`
        stdWrap.wrap3 = <ul>|</ul>

        NO = 1
        NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
        NO.allWrap.insertData = 1
        NO.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title
    }
}
```

On a page-tree like this

```
+- A
|  +- AA
|  +- AB
|
+- B
   +- BA
   +- BB
```

The rendered HTML result looks like this

```
<li><a href="/ts/a" title="A">A</a></li>
<ul>
  <li><a href="/ts/a">URL from Level 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/ts/a/aa" title="AA">AA</a></li>
  <li><a href="/ts/a/ab" title="AB">AB</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="/ts/b" title="B">B</a></li>
<ul>
  <li><a href="/ts/b">URL from Level 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/ts/b/ba" title="BA">BA</a></li>
  <li><a href="/ts/b/bb" title="BB">BB</a></li>
</ul>
```

### Update on custom rendering replacing static `value` property

Instead of using property `stdWrap.prepend.value` (like shown in example above), other `cObject` instructions could be used as well - in this case for instance `RECORDS` (see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Records/Index.html)

The following example renders fields `nav_title` (and if that's not defined `title` as fallback) of the parent page.

```
page.10 {
    # ...
    2 {
        # ...
        stdWrap.prepend {
            # using `cObject` instead of `value`
            cObject = RECORDS
            cObject {
                tables = pages
                source.field = pid
                # rendering definition for retrieved record of table pages
                conf.pages = TEXT
                # `//` is used as fallback delimiter here, NOT as comment
                conf.pages.field = nav_title // title
            }
            # ...
```

Comment: Hi Oliver, it works great! One more doubt: value = URL from Level 1 ---> I would like to put here the navigation title of the url from level 1. What would be the code be for that?

Comment: @CondorIdiomas I've added an example on how to render custom content of the linked page using `cObject` property and `RECORDS` instruction

Comment: Wonderful. Works perfect. Thx!